# In AG Grid React Want single scrolling option for all the tables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have 7 tables in one parent component with total 5000 data and now all the tables have individual scrolling so I want a single scrolling option for all the tables.[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1QZB.png)

This is common component for all tables

```
import React, { useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css"; // Core CSS
import "ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css"; // Theme
import { defaultColumnsSize } from "./utils";

const AGGrid = ({
  data,
  columnDefs,
  columnSizes,
  setColumnSizes,
  gridApiRef,
  quickFilterText,
  alignedGrids,
  onColumnMoved,
}) => {

  const containerStyle = useMemo(
    () => ({
      width: "100%",
      height: "55vh",
      alignItems: "center",
    }),
    []
  );
  const defaultColDef = useMemo(
    () => ({
      flex: 1,
      minWidth: 50,
    }),
    []
  );

  const onColumnResized = (event) => {
    const columnApi = event.columnApi;
    const column = event.column;

    if (columnApi && column) {
      const newWidth = column.getActualWidth();
      const colId = column.getColId();

      // Log the resized column details
      console.log(`Column ${colId} resized to ${newWidth}px`);

      // Accumulate column sizes
      setColumnSizes((prevSizes) => ({
        ...prevSizes,
        [colId]: newWidth,
      }));
    } else {
      console.warn("Column or columnApi is undefined in onColumnResized");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const newData3 = {};
    for (const key in defaultColumnsSize) {
      const maxSize = defaultColumnsSize[key].minSize;
      const defaultValue = defaultColumnsSize[key].defaultSize;
      const value =
        columnSizes[key] !== undefined ? columnSizes[key] : defaultValue;
      newData3[key] = Math.max(maxSize, value);
    }
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      // for delay
      // console.log("table-Column-Size: ------>>> ", newData3);
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [columnSizes]);

  const getRowStyle = () => {
    // if (params.node.rowIndex % 2 === 0) {
    return {
      // suppressCellSelection: true,
      // height: "auto",
      // textAlign: "center",
      // display: "flex",
      // alignItems: "center",
    };
    // }
  };

  const rowStyle = { padding: "5px" };

  return (
    // <div className={"ag-theme-quartz-dark"} style={containerStyle}>
    <div style={containerStyle} className={"ag-theme-quartz-dark"}>
      <AgGridReact
        rowStyle={rowStyle}
        ref={gridApiRef}
        suppressRowHoverHighlight={true}
        rowData={data}
        // rowData={rowData}
        // onPaginationScroll={onPaginationScroll}
        rowHeight={70}
        columnDefs={columnDefs}
        defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
        suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns={true}
        onColumnResized={onColumnResized}
        onColumnMoved={onColumnMoved}
        // onGridReady={onGridReady}
        // domLayout="autoHeight"
        // pagination
        suppressMaxRenderedRowRestriction={true}
        quickFilterText={quickFilterText}
        // domLayout="print"
        alignedGrids={alignedGrids}
        popupParent={document.body}
        getRowStyle={getRowStyle}
      />
    </div>
    // </div>
  );
};

export default AGGrid;
```

Common component is use in parent component

```
  <Accordion open={open} toggle={toggle}>
            {/* 1 - Start - Project_Requested */}
            {allDataProjectManagement?.requested?.length !== 0 && (
              <AccordionItem
                id="requested"
                style={{
                  borderColor: ProjectStatusColorCode.get("requested"),
                }}
              >
                <AccordionHeader
                  targetId="1"
                  className="custom-accordion-header"
                >
                  <div className="accordion-sub-header">
                    <h3 style={{ fontWeight: "500", margin: "0px" }}>
                      Project Requested
                    </h3>
                    <div className="number-project">
                      Number of Projects :&nbsp;
                      {/* {projects?.data?.requested?.data?.length} */}
                      {allDataProjectManagement?.requested?.length}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </AccordionHeader>
                <AccordionBody
                  className="main-project-table-accordion-body"
                  accordionId="1"
                >
                  <AGGrid
                    data={allDataProjectManagement?.requested}
                    columnDefs={columnDefs}
                    pageSize={50}
                    columnSizes={columnSizes}
                    setColumnSizes={setColumnSizes}
                    gridApiRef={gridApiRef1}
                    quickFilterText={searchText}
                    onGridReady={onGridReady}
                    alignedGrids={[
                      gridApiRef2,
                      gridApiRef3,
                      gridApiRef4,
                      gridApiRef5,
                      gridApiRef6,
                      gridApiRef7,
                    ]}
                    onColumnMoved={onColumnMoved}
                  />
                </AccordionBody>
              </AccordionItem>
            )}
            {/* 1 - End - Project_Requested */}

            {/* 2 - Start - Footage_Received  */}
            {allDataProjectManagement?.footage_received?.length !== 0 && (
              <AccordionItem
                id="footage_received"
                style={{
                  borderColor: ProjectStatusColorCode.get("footage_received"),
                }}
              >
                <AccordionHeader
                  targetId="2"
                  className="custom-accordion-header"
                >
                  <div className="accordion-sub-header">
                    <h3 style={{ fontWeight: "500", margin: "0px" }}>
                      Footage Received
                    </h3>
                    <div className="number-project">
                      Number of Projects :&nbsp;
                      {allDataProjectManagement?.footage_received?.length}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </AccordionHeader>
                <AccordionBody
                  className="main-project-table-accordion-body"
                  accordionId="2"
                >
                  <AGGrid
                    data={allDataProjectManagement?.footage_received}
                    columnDefs={columnDefs}
                    pageSize={50}
                    columnSizes={columnSizes}
                    setColumnSizes={setColumnSizes}
                    gridApiRef={gridApiRef2}
                    onGridReady={onGridReady}
                    alignedGrids={[
                      gridApiRef1,
                      gridApiRef3,
                      gridApiRef4,
                      gridApiRef5,
                      gridApiRef6,
                      gridApiRef7,
                    ]}
                    onColumnMoved={onColumnMoved}
                    quickFilterText={searchText}
                  />
                  {/* {TableFunctionTest(projects?.data?.footage_received)} */}
                </AccordionBody>
              </AccordionItem>
            )}
            {/* 2 - End - Footage_Received  */}
```

i tried this above code but if i use DomLayout= autoheight or print it will taking load

and if i want to do with the help of backend how can i do that

can i get data on scroll ?

because i have one parent and want only one scroll.